# Javascript test() function with regular expression that looks for angle brackets

Tags: javascript

I've been completely stumped on writing a regex (Regular Expression) that looks for angle brackets. I need a regular expression that will output a message if any angle brackets are found in the input field, no matter what the context may be. So basically if there is any angle brackets I want an error message to be outputted. This is what my code looks like:

```
else if (verifyInput4.value = /()/.test(verifyInput4) == false) {
    document.getElementById('custComplaintSpan').innerHTML = "Invalid Characters";
    document.getElementById('custComplaint').style.borderColor = "red";
}
```

I need the regex in place of where I have the /()/ written in my code. I've tried looking for a solution but no luck. I just need a simple regex that will prevent any angle brackets in the input field. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "<|>"; see here: https://regex101.com/r/uA01xP/2

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I really appreciate it!